# Change the full name of a species while retaining the first letter

Tags: r, regex, string

I'm trying to rename some species names, e.g. "Abies bornmuelleriana" in "A. bornmuelleriana" for a long species list within one column, named "species" of a data frame "df", and `mutate` it in new column, named "species2".

I'm trying this

```
df$species2 <- sub("(?<=.).*$", "", df$species, perl=TRUE)
```

but it just keeping the first letter but I want also the second part of the name

How can do it? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace anything that is not upper case letter until the first space with a dot and a space.

```r
species <- "Abies bornmuelleriana"

sub("[^A-Z].+? ", ". ", species)
[1] "A. bornmuelleriana"
```

Answer (score 2):

Taking everything what is not a space `\\S*` after the first and replace it with a `.`.

```
sub("(?<=.)\\S*", ".", "Abies bornmuelleriana", perl=TRUE)
#[1] "A. bornmuelleriana"
```

In your case `.*` takes everything until the end.
In case only lowercase letters follow the first letter in the first word it will also work using:

```
sub("[a-z]+", ".", "Abies bornmuelleriana")
#[1] "A. bornmuelleriana"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a tidyverse solution suitable for packet names' processing:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr) 

species <- c("Abies bornmuelleriana", 
"Mentha piperita") 

paste0(species %>%
str_split("") %>%
lapply(FUN = function(x) x[1]) %>%
unlist, 
". ", 
species %>%
str_split(" ") %>%
lapply(FUN = function(x) x[2]) %>%
unlist)
```